# How to code build.finalisedBy.uploadArchives within gradle.build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My gradle.build file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile gradleApi()

    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.10'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///Users/BrionMarkov/.m2/repository/")
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have to manually execute `uploadArchives`, what I would like is that each time I build (or rebuild) my project successfully uploadArchives is executed automatically.

I've tried `build.finalisedBy.uploadArchives` however my build fails with

```
Error:(25, 0) No such property: uploadArchives for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency
```

How can I achieve automatically executed uploadArchives?

**UPDATE**

I change mu build file to the following

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile gradleApi()

    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.10'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///Users/BrionMarkov/.m2/repository/")
        }
    }
```

}

build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)

This doesn't generate any error messages, however when I clean and rebuild my main project the upload is not triggered.

What am I still doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I use "`clean.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)`" then uploadArchives is automatically executed, however "`build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)`" does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line to your `build.gradle`:

```
build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)
```